# How to find the producer of rabbitmq message?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a setup where multiple processes generate and published message to RMQ.  In my case, a queue reserved for one process is being used by some other process which I am not able to figure out.
Is there a way in RabbitMQ UI or logs to get the know IP from which the message was published?